# Show elements after specific Class

Tags: html, jquery

With jQuery I want to hide all `li` elements and show only `li` with class `.selected` and others elements that have a minus (`-`) symbol.

This is the result I expect when I click on the button:

```
<ul>
  <li class="selected">Item 5</li>
  <li>- Item 6</li>
  <li>- Item 7</li>
  <li>- Item 8</li>
</ul>

<input type="button" id="btm" value="show" />
```

```js
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
$j(document).ready(function() {
  $j("input#btm").bind("click", function() {
    for (var i = 1; i <= 12; i++) {
      if ($j('.chzn-results li:nth-child(' + i + ')').hasClass("selected") || $j('.chzn-results li:nth-child(' + i + ')').text().indexOf('- ') >= 0) {
        $j('.chzn-results li:nth-child(' + i + ')').show();
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="chzn-results">
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>- Item 2</li>
  <li>- Item 3</li>
  <li>- Item 4</li>
  <li class="selected">Item 5</li>
  <li>- Item 6</li>
  <li>- Item 7</li>
  <li>- Item 8</li>
  <li>Item 9</li>
  <li>Item 10</li>
  <li>Item 11</li>
  <li>- Item 12</li>
</ul>

<input type="button" id="btm" value="show" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a combination of `.index()` and `.slice()` to select items up to the `selected` one.

To find the first non-dash entry would be much easier if you could add some classes, but looks like you're using `chosen` so possibly can't change the html.

Keeping it to a simple `for` loop with `break` when a match is no longer found gives:

```js
var li = $("ul.chzn-results>li");
var pos = li.filter(".selected").index();
var endpos = pos+1;
for (var i = endpos; i<li.length; ++i)
{
    //console.log(li.eq(i).text().substr(0, 1))
    if (li.eq(i).text().substr(0, 1) != "-")
        break;
    endpos = i;
}

li.slice(0, pos).hide();
li.slice(endpos+1).hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="chzn-results">
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>- Item 2</li>
  <li>- Item 3</li>
  <li>- Item 4</li>
  <li class="selected">Item 5</li>
  <li>- Item 6</li>
  <li>- Item 7</li>
  <li>- Item 8</li>
  <li>Item 9</li>
  <li>Item 10</li>
  <li>Item 11</li>
  <li>- Item 12</li>
</ul>

<input type="button" id="btm" value="show" />
```

---

Bit cleaner without the `for` loop

```js
var li = $("ul.chzn-results>li");
var pos = li.filter(".selected").index();
// can all be on one line, separated for readability
var endpos = li.filter(".selected")
               .nextAll()
               .filter((i,e) => $(e).text().substr(0,1) != "-")
               .first()
               .index() - 1;
li.slice(0, pos).hide();
li.slice(endpos+1).hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="chzn-results">
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>- Item 2</li>
  <li>- Item 3</li>
  <li>- Item 4</li>
  <li class="selected">Item 5</li>
  <li>- Item 6</li>
  <li>- Item 7</li>
  <li>- Item 8</li>
  <li>Item 9</li>
  <li>Item 10</li>
  <li>Item 11</li>
  <li>- Item 12</li>
</ul>

<input type="button" id="btm" value="show" />
```

---

For the comment, if a "child" item is selected, get the "parent" first

```js
var li = $("ul.chzn-results>li");
var pos = li.filter(".selected")
            .prevAll()
            .filter((i,e) => $(e).text().substr(0,1) != "-")
            .first()
            .index();
// can all be on one line, separated for readability
var endpos = li.filter(".selected")
               .nextAll()
               .filter((i,e) => $(e).text().substr(0,1) != "-")
               .first()
               .index() - 1;
li.slice(0, pos).hide();
li.slice(endpos+1).hide();
```

```css
.selected { color: red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="chzn-results">
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>- Item 2</li>
  <li>- Item 3</li>
  <li>- Item 4</li>
  <li>Item 5</li>
  <li class="selected">- Item 6</li>
  <li>- Item 7</li>
  <li>- Item 8</li>
  <li>Item 9</li>
  <li>Item 10</li>
  <li>Item 11</li>
  <li>- Item 12</li>
</ul>

<input type="button" id="btm" value="show" />
```

Comment: Perfect! This solution works great for me. Thank you. :) But if instead the "selected" class is positioned in an element with the minus symbol. For example i have <ul><li>item6</li><li class="selected">- Item 7</li><li>item8</li></ul>. How can I get the same result? Thanks so much

Comment: By "same result" I guess you mean as if Item5 was selected.   You would first get the "parent" node, eg something like `$("li.selected").prevAll().filter((i,e)=>$(e).text().substr(0,1)!="-").first()` You could use a similar filter instead of the `for` loop (but `nextAll`)

Comment: Ok...so the code is this for example? var li = $j(".chzn-results li");var pos = li.filter(".result-selected").index();var endpos = pos+1;for (var i = endpos; i<li.length; ++i){if (li.eq(i).text().substr(0, 1) != "-"){break;endpos = i;}$j("li.return-selected").prevAll().filter((i,e)=>$j(e).text().substr(0,1)!="-").first().show();}li.slice(0, pos).hide();li.slice(endpos+1).hide();

Comment: If you're using `pos` and `endpos` then set them up correctly in the setup phase.  Then just show/hide using those variables.  Don't mix and match, it's too messy.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.addBack()` and `.nextAll()` to traverse through all li after selected class and then use each loop and compare each `li` if condition statisfy show that li.

**Demo Code** :

```js
$("input#btm").bind("click", function() {
  $(".chzn-results li").hide() //hide all
  $(".chzn-results li.selected").nextAll().addBack().each(function() {
    //check condtion
    if ($(this).hasClass("selected") || $(this).text().indexOf("-") > -1) {
      $(this).show() //show ..
    } else {
      return false; //break loop :P 
    }
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="chzn-results">
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>- Item 2</li>
  <li>- Item 3</li>
  <li>- Item 4</li>
  <li class="selected">Item 5</li>
  <li>- Item 6</li>
  <li>- Item 7</li>
  <li>- Item 8</li>
  <li>Item 9</li>
  <li>Item 10</li>
  <li>Item 11</li>
  <li>- Item 12</li>
</ul>

<input type="button" id="btm" value="show" />
```

Comment: As I understand the question, the "next" should be up-to the next "header"/"parent" record so stop at Item 9 as per OPs example (not include Item 12)

Comment: "header"/"parent" ? i didn't understood  that :D.

Comment: From the data provided, it looks like it's a representation of a tree view (can't really show in comments) with the "dash" items (2,3,4,6,7,8 etc) being "child" or "sub" items.  So the ones without a dash are the "headers" or "parents" of the "child"/"sub" items.  I read OPs request as: if a "parent" was selected show its "children" as you would with a treeview expand / collapse (though not exactly the same as doesn't show other "headers")

Comment: Oh , now i understood . Thank you i have updated my answer :P

Answer (score 0):

In this solution, I used the double exclusion of the selectors required for display using the `not()` method, which specifies the tag `li` with the class `selected`, and all subsequent tags `li` containing the character **(-)** defining the `:contains()` selector.

```js
$("#btn").on("click", function () {
    $(".chzn-results >").not($("li.selected")).not($("li.selected ~ :contains(-)")).hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="chzn-results">
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>- Item 2</li>
    <li>- Item 3</li>
    <li>- Item 4</li>
    <li class="selected">Item 5</li>
    <li>- Item 6</li>
    <li>- Item 7</li>
    <li>- Item 8</li>
    <li>Item 9</li>
    <li>Item 10</li>
    <li>Item 11</li>
    <li>- Item 12</li>
</ul>

<input type="button" id="btn" value="show" />
```